# Internet explorer z-index not working with open flash chart

Tags: php, html, css, internet-explorer, open-flash-chart

How to overlap an element over Open-Flash-charts Element that is positioned relatively in Internet Explorer 10.

Its perfectly work in Chrome and firefox and it respectively work with other elements using Z-index also in ie10 but with open-flash-chart, It fails in IE10.

It always appears behind the relatively positioned Open-flash-charts element.Have you any idea then help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to the flash `<object>` tag:

```
<object ...>
    ....
    <param name="wmode" value="opaque">
</object>
```

Otherwise, Flash elements go above everything: https://drupal.org/node/964664

If you're using swfobject, you can still specify the parameter.

```
swfobject.embedSWF( "open-flash-chart.swf", "chart1", "100%", "300", 
  "9.0.0", "expressInstal1l.swf", {
    "data-file":"data_files/datafile.txt", 
    "wmode":"opaque"
  } );
```

Comment: Thanx But i have not any object directly called from html here is my code for html  <div  id="chart1"></div>. and in script i use swfobject.embedSWF(
  "open-flash-chart.swf", "chart1",
  "100%", "300", "9.0.0", "expressInstal1l.swf",
  {"data-file":"data_files/datafile.txt"} );

Comment: @Sameer that doesn't matter.  swfobject can also specify that parameter

Comment: You still have the z-index? You still need it... and if `opaque` doesn't work, try `transparent` though technically the result should be the same in this case.